How can I put a where clause when doing a table count?
I am doing a table count as follows:
select sum([rows])
from sys.partitions
where object_id=object_id('MyTable')
    and index_id in (0,1)

There is a column in the MyTable table called Department.
I want to filter the results above to only count rows where the value in the Department column is HR
Can I add this too the select above, rather than counting from MyTable directly? Perhaps something like this:
select sum([rows])
from sys.partitions
where object_id=object_id('MyTable' where Department ='HR')
    and index_id in (0,1)

Similarly, if i have a date field can i do something like this?
select sum(p.[rows])
from sys.partitions p
join mytable t on p.object_id = object_id('mytable ')
where p.index_id in (0, 1)
    and year(t.creationdate) = 2023

I tried that but it returned an enormous number like its a union, when I only expected 300000 rows.

This is a query for sys.partitions (a system catalog view)  - it's not a database table like myTable - I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using. There are syntax and functionality differences between them, so knowing what you're using is necessary. It's a waste of both our time and yours when someone writes an answer to your question only to find out it doesn't work on your RDBMS.

Why can't you ask the table directly? Because MyTable is the only place you'll be able to get this information.

cause it is a table that has over 600,000,000 records, not efficient

@Melissa The cardinality (rowcount) of a database table has nothing to do with "efficiency" here: databases are designed to hold and processs hundreds of billions of rows if necessary. You need to reassess your priors as you seem to be operating on some fundamental misunderstandings or misconceptions of how RDBMS scale.

sys.partitions can only tell you how many rows are estimated in the whole partition, so unless the table is partitioned on values of Department, you cannot filter this query.
The only definitive answer is to query the table itself. If that is not efficient then you probably need an index on Department.
But as a first option, you could query the stats histogram for the most recent stats update. This is unlikely to work in many cases, because you'd need to find a stats object which has this column as the leading column, and happens to have a histogram step of exactly that value. Note that there are a maximum of 200 histogram steps, so this may be more or less likely given your data. It also may be inaccurate, especially for a large table where stats updates are infrequent.
select top (1)
  h.equal_rows
from sys.tables t
join sys.stats s on s.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.stats_columns sc on sc.object_id = s.object_id and sc.stats_id = s.stats_id
join sys.columns c on c.object_id = s.object_id and c.column_id = sc.column_id
cross apply sys.dm_db_stats_histogram(s.object_id, s.stats_id) h
where t.name = N'MyTable'
  and c.name = N'Department'
  and s.has_filter = 0  -- not filtered stats
  and sc.stats_column_id = 1  -- must be leading column of stats
  and h.range_high_key = cast('HR' as sql_variant);

db<>fiddle

I am a bit unclear why you aren't doing the count from the MyTable directly but you need to join MyTable to sys.partitions using the object_id
select sum(p.[rows])
from sys.partitions p
join MyTable t on p.object_id = object_id('MyTable')
where p.index_id in (0, 1)
  and t.Department = 'HR'


object_id needs schema_id qualification.

I have updated the question with a column that is a date field

I have updated the question with a column that is a date field. If i take out the where clause , the join is wrong , returns wrong number of rows should only be 800000
